# Custom CSS is not overriding the materialize CSS

Tags: css, materialize

i have set the custom css link below the materialize css but it isn't overriding

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Shalom Kang Kong</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/style.css">
</head>
<body>
```

Comment: Welcome, to get a proper answer to this question you should provide more information like your folder structure or which particular case is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Link order doesn't automaticly mean one stylesheet will ovetwrite all of the other styles. One way to have css property overwritten by another one is increasing specificity of selectors you are using.